# VBA Code to automatically add a comment if a cell contains a certain letter

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I just started learning VBA last week and now I am trying to solve the following problem: If users type in a certain letter (and only these specified letters), then a comment should be added automatically to the selected cell. The comment should contain a small "header" and then an explanatory text, which is typed in by the user. 
The shown code actually worked, but only for the first cell I tested it with. So, when I executed it the first time, the comment automatically appeared with the specified text as I intended, but in the next cell it didn't. Even restarting Excel didn't help - so now even the first cell doesn't create the comment. That's why I am confused.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim x

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Value = "" Then

    Application.Undo
    x = Target.Value
    Target.Value = ""
    On Error Resume Next

    If (x = "A") Or (x = "B") Or (x = "C") Or (x = "D") Or (x = "E") Then Target.Comment.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0   

ElseIf Target.Value = "A" Then
    Target.AddComment ("explanationA: ")

ElseIf Target.Value = "B" Then
    Target.AddComment "explanationB: "

ElseIf Target.Value = "C" Then
    Target.AddComment "explanationC: "

ElseIf Target.Value = "D" Then
    Target.AddComment "explanationD: "

ElseIf Target.Value = "E" Then
    Target.AddComment "explanationE: "

End If
End Sub
```

I have specified to "Worksheet" and "Change".

There is also an additional question, which would be of interest for me: is there a possibility, that excel automatically selects the comment after it was generated, so that the user can type in some explanatory information without needing to select the comment manually?

Help is appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Use InStr(1, UCase(Target.Value), "A") > 0 instead of Target.Value="A", etc. So that you are looking for if the string Contains "A" rather than that it is solely equal to a. Also, this will check for if "A" or "a" is entered.

Comment: Thank you, but I want the code only to check for the letter "A"/"a" in the cell. So, if the cell contains e.g. "Ab" then the comment should not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Option Compare Text` at the declarations section (top) of your module to allow comparisons for the entire module to be case-insensitive.

Although the code within the sub routine "MyCompare" is identical, their outcome is different:

```
Sub MyCompare

    Debug.print "a" = "A"
    ' Prints False

End Sub
```

```
Option Compare Text

Sub MyCompare

    Debug.Print "a" = "A"
    ' Prints True

End Sub
```

---

But anyway, let's get to your *actual* problem. It's with this line in your code:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Notice the reason your code worked the first time was because you captured the `Worksheet_Change` event. But now you just disabled events within this code and never turned it back on, therefore you will no longer be able to run your `Worksheet_Change` subroutine.

Just make sure to turn it back on before you exit your code. Also, it would be wise to handle your errors in a way that will enable events rather than prematurely stopping your code, which would keep them disabled.

The way I usually enable events without running a Sub is by using the debug window. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> within the VBE to open this window, then within the window simply type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and press <kbd>Return</kbd> and you've just change that property.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! There was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Something quick and easy would be like this below;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Select Case Target.Cells
    Case Is = "A": Target.AddComment ("explanationA: ")
    Case Is = "B": Target.AddComment ("explanationB: ")
    Case Is = "C": Target.AddComment ("explanationC: ")
    Case Is = "D": Target.AddComment ("explanationD: ")
    Case Is = "E": Target.AddComment ("explanationE: ")
End Select
On Error Resume Next
End Sub
```

Just remember to put the code on the sheet you want it to happen on, and it appears its case sensitive also.

Comment: Just modify Target.Cells to UCase(Target.Value) and it's no longer case sensitive.

Comment: Yeah that will enable lower case, if you wanted either "A" or "a" then simple change the case to:

Case "A", "a": Target.AddComment ("explanationA: ")

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was very helpful to write more comprehensive code!